# Redis user management system

Tags: mysql, database, redis

I'm converting my old MySQL based user management system to Redis, and
have run into a few problems...

I am using a combination of HASHs and SETs as the foundation of the system.

Just some pseudo-code

```
let uid=incr user_id_counter

    hset joe@dom.com user user:uid
    hset user:uid email joe#dom.com
    hset user:uid gender m
    hset user:uid year_of_birth 1972
    hset user:uid fav_band acdc
    sadd maleUsers uid
    sadd born1972Users uid
```

at this point all is well, and I can do search using sinter
for example:

```
sinter maleUsers born1972
or
sinter femaleUsers born1980
```

This is assuming I make a seperate set for each year of birh

```
sad bornXXXX uid
```

This is I can stomach - but how would I handle fav band ?
Surely, I wouldn't make a set for all possible bands ?

Eventually I would like to be able to do detailed searches such as,

```
sinter maleUsers born1980 genreRock genreMetal homeTownSydney
```

Is there a more sophisticated way to do relational queries?

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan or Redis. But I am afraid that your approach is quite wrong. Your primary storage for user credentials should still be a traditional RDBMS, and sticking with MySQL is a great way to do.

NoSQL databases, and Redis in particular, are meant to do other things.

Redis is memory-based. Yes, you can persist everything to an hard drive but when you machine boots up it will load everything from your hard drive to the memory. And - your storage cap is your machine's memory. So unless you count on not too many users, I wouldn't recommend Redis as a primary source of storage. You can still leverage Redis for secondary access to your users (2nd level cache for example) but not as a primary source.

You can use disk-based NoSQL databases (MongoDB, CouchDB, Cassandra and all those) for your users database, which is a better choice than Redis, but I still highly recommend traditional RDBMS for this. You want to hold your most critical data in a reliable transaction-based system.

Answer (score 0):

*But how would I handle fav band ? Surely, I wouldn't make a set for all possible bands ?*

Well, this is exactly what you are supposed to do. With Redis, such relation is represented by a reference to the band, part of the user definition, and by a set associated to the band containing references to all users.

This association have to be kept manually, but you can leverage MULTI/EXEC blocks to guarantee data consistency in a concurrent environment.

*Is there a more sophisticated way to do relational queries?*

Yes, by using a relational database instead of Redis. If you are looking for relational queries, why not using a RDBMS? What's wrong with MySQL?